# How to slice one MultiIndex DataFrame with the MultiIndex of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 levels of a MultiIndex. I am trying to pull out rows of this dataframe according to a list of values that correspond to two of the levels.

I have something like this:

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'can']], names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
data = np.arange(len(ix))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ix, columns=['hi'])
print(df)

           hi
a b   c      
1 foo baz   0
      can   1
  bar baz   2
      can   3
2 foo baz   4
      can   5
  bar baz   6
      can   7
3 foo baz   8
      can   9
  bar baz  10
      can  11
```

Now I want to take all rows where index levels 'b' and 'c' are in this index:

```
ix_use = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('foo', 'can'), ('bar', 'baz')], names=['b', 'c'])
```

i.e. values of `hi` having `('foo', 'can')` or `('bar', 'baz')` in levels `b` and `c` respectively: `(1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10)`.

So I'd like to take a `slice(None)` on the first level, and pull out specific tuples on the second and third levels.

Initially I thought that passing a multi-index object to .loc would pull out the values / levels that I wanted, but this isn't working. What's the best way to do something like this?

Comment: I had a couple of different attempts at getting this to work. I think I've found a decent workaround to the fact that this currently seems to be a bit hard. Try it out!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a way to get this slice:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, ('foo','bar'), 'can'], :]
```

yielding

```
           hi
a b   c      
1 bar can   3
  foo can   1
2 bar can   7
  foo can   5
3 bar can  11
  foo can   9
```

Note that you might need to sort MultiIndex before you can slice it. Well pandas is kind enough to warn if you need to do it:

```
KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (3), lexsort depth (1)'
```

You can read more on how to use slicers in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

If for some reason using slicers is not an option here is a way to get the same slice using `.isin()` method:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('b').isin(ix_use.get_level_values(0)) & df.index.get_level_values('c').isin(ix_use.get_level_values(1))]
```

Which is clearly not as concise.

**UPDATE:**

For the conditions that you have updated here is a way to do it:

```
cond1 = (df.index.get_level_values('b').isin(['foo'])) & (df.index.get_level_values('c').isin(['can']))
cond2 = (df.index.get_level_values('b').isin(['bar'])) & (df.index.get_level_values('c').isin(['baz']))
df[cond1 | cond2]
```

producing:

```
           hi
a b   c      
1 foo can   1
  bar baz   2
2 foo can   5
  bar baz   6
3 foo can   9
  bar baz  10
```

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for, but I should have phrased the question more clearly. In reality, what I need is a value from level "c" that is dependent on the value in level "b".

E.g., any time that level "b" is 'foo', I want the value where level "c" is 'can', and any time the level "b" is 'bar', I want the value where level "c" is 'baz'

Comment: Updated the answer with those two conditions, which should give an idea how to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [the `query()` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) just like in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40817489/2303761).

Simply using this, which I think is a more natural way to express:

```
In [27]: df.query("(b == 'foo' and c == 'can') or (b == 'bar' and c == 'baz')")
Out[27]: 
           hi
a b   c      
1 foo can   1
  bar baz   2
2 foo can   5
  bar baz   6
3 foo can   9
  bar baz  10
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it interesting that this doesn't work:

```
In [45]: df.loc[(idx[:, 'foo', 'can'], idx[:, 'bar', 'baz']), ]
Out[45]: 
           hi
a b   c      
1 bar baz   2
      can   3
  foo baz   0
      can   1
2 bar baz   6
      can   7
  foo baz   4
      can   5
3 bar baz  10
      can  11
  foo baz   8
      can   9
```

It sort of looks like it "should", somehow. In any case, here's a reasonable workaround:

Let's assume the tuples you want to slice by are in the index of another `DataFrame` (since it sounds like they probably *are* in your case!).

```
In [53]: ix_use = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('foo', 'can'), ('bar', 'baz')], names=['b', 'c'])
In [55]: other = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=1), index=ix_use)
In [56]: other
Out[56]: 
         a
b   c     
foo can  1
bar baz  1
```

Now to slice `df` by the index of `other` we can use the fact that `.loc`/`.ix` allow you to give a list of tuples (see the last example [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)).

First let's build the list of tuples we want:

```
In [13]: idx = [(x, ) + y for x in df.index.levels[0] for y in other.index.values]
In [14]: idx
Out[14]: 
[(1, 'foo', 'can'),
 (1, 'bar', 'baz'),
 (2, 'foo', 'can'),
 (2, 'bar', 'baz'),
 (3, 'foo', 'can'),
 (3, 'bar', 'baz')]
```

Now we can pass this list to `.ix` or `.loc`:

```
In [17]: df.ix[idx]
Out[17]: 
           hi
a b   c      
1 foo can   1
  bar baz   2
2 foo can   5
  bar baz   6
3 foo can   9
  bar baz  10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df


ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'can']], names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
data = np.arange(len(ix))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ix, columns=['hi'])
print(df)

"""
           hi
a b   c      
1 foo baz   0
      can   1
  bar baz   2
      can   3
2 foo baz   4
      can   5
  bar baz   6
      can   7
3 foo baz   8
      can   9
  bar baz  10
      can  11

"""
a = (df.index.get_level_values('b') =='foo')
b = (df.index.get_level_values('c') =='can')
ab = (a & b)
dab = df[a & b]
print(dab)

"""
          hi
a b   c      
1 foo can   1
2 foo can   5
3 foo can   9
"""
a1 = (df.index.get_level_values('b') =='bar')
b1 = (df.index.get_level_values('c') =='baz')
ab1 = (a1 & b1)
dab1 = df[a1 & b1]
print(dab1)
"""
           hi
a b   c      
1 bar baz   2
2 bar baz   6
3 bar baz  10
"""

abab = df[ab | ab1]
print(abab)
"""
           hi
a b   c      
1 foo can   1
  bar baz   2
2 foo can   5
  bar baz   6
3 foo can   9
  bar baz  10
"""
```