# Indexing with multiindex dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

Consider the following example data:

```
data = {"Taxon": ["Firmicutes"]*5,
        "Patient": range(5),
        "Tissue": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=5),
        "Stool": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=5)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(["Taxon", "Patient"])
print(df)

                    Stool  Tissue
Taxon      Patient               
Firmicutes 0          740     389
           1          786     815
           2          178     265
           3          841     484
           4          211     534
```

So, How can I query the dataframe only with the second level index `Patient` only? For example, I'd like to know all the data with respect to `Patient 2`.

I've tried `data[data.index.get_level_values(1)==2]`, and it worked fine. But is there any way to achieve the same with one these (`loc`,`iloc` or `ix`) indexing methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simpliest is use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
np.random.seed(100)
names = ['Taxon','Patient']
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Firmicutes', 'another'], range(1, 6)], names=names)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,2)), columns=['Tissue','Stool'], index=mux)
print (df)
                    Tissue  Stool
Taxon      Patient               
Firmicutes 1             8      8
           2             3      7
           3             7      0
           4             4      2
           5             5      2
another    1             2      2
           2             1      0
           3             8      4
           4             0      9
           5             6      2
```

---

```
print (df.xs(2, level=1))
            Tissue  Stool
Taxon                    
Firmicutes       3      7
another          1      0

#if need also level Patient
print (df.xs(2, level=1, drop_level=False))
                    Tissue  Stool
Taxon      Patient               
Firmicutes 2             3      7
another    2             1      0
```

Solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - is possible specify `axis`:

```
print (df.loc(axis=0)[:,2])
                    Tissue  Stool
Taxon      Patient               
Firmicutes 2             3      7
another    2             1      0
```

Comment: Great help. The method works like a charm, and I didn't even know it had the `level` option. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `loc` one still doesn't work, and give an error: `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'`. Have no idea why that is.

Comment: You need `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex)

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I typically just use df.loc[:, ('Upper Index', ('lower_idx_v1', 'lower_idx_v2'))] -- can't that work here? I find that simpler.

Comment: @ZachOakes- If need select by multiple values, then `df.xs(2, level=1)` cannot be used, but if need select only by one level,simplier should be `df.xs(2, level=1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `pd.IndexSlice` which is exactly what you are looking for. See the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).

Some dummy data:

```
data = {"Taxon": ["Firmicutes"]*5,
        "Patient": range(5),
        "Tissue": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=5),
        "Stool": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=5)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(["Taxon", "Patient"])
print(df)

                    Stool  Tissue
Taxon      Patient               
Firmicutes 0          158     137
           1          697     980
           2          751     759
           3          171     556
           4          701     620
```

You can write it explicitly like:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 2), :]

                        Stool   Tissue
Taxon       Patient         
Firmicutes        2     751     759
```

Or you may use the more readable pd.IndexSlice:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 2], :]

                        Stool   Tissue
Taxon       Patient         
Firmicutes        2     751     759
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your second solution throws me `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'`. What is that about?

Comment: @JamesWong It works in my dummy example as updated in the answer. As the `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted` mentions, try to sort the index of your MultiIndexed data frame first with `df = df.sort_index()` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266600/how-to-slice-one-multiindex-dataframe-with-the-multiindex-of-another) in more detail.