# Bug with capital letter label in pandas multi index

Tags: python, pandas

I have come across a bug in my code below. If the second element of my categories list is a capital letter then the resulting values of my data frame 'change_1_month_df' are NaN. If I use a lower case letter then the random numbers are correctly inserted. Any Ideas? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = ['d1','d2']
categories = ['a','b']
sub_categories = ['f','g']
my_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([categories,sub_categories])
change_1_month_df = pd.DataFrame(index=my_index,columns=dates)

for a in categories:
    for d in dates:
        print a,d
        if a == 'W':
            None
        else:
            change_1_month_df.ix[a].ix['f'][d] = np.random.randn(1)
            change_1_month_df.ix[a].ix['g'][d] = np.random.randn(1)

change_1_month_df
```

Comment: `.ix` is deprected use `iloc` instead.

Comment: Thanks, the problem still exists with .loc

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.7

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this ? By using `.loc` select the multi index

```
for a in categories:
    for d in dates:

        if a == 'W':
            None
        else:
            change_1_month_df.loc[(a, 'f'), d]=np.random.randn(1)[0]
            change_1_month_df.loc[(a, 'g'), d]=np.random.randn(1)[0]

change_1_month_df
```

Comment: Wen, you are so right, it has to do with the chaining of .loc or .ix, a copy is getting created in memory and not assigning it to the original dataframe.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. I was refraining from posting this because I did not know why the original method returns NaNs.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for his method, it work on my side , just give back the warning .ix .

Comment: Interesting... if I changed `b` to `B`, it did not work anymore.

Comment: @BoscoBaracus notice , you method still work , but suggested to using the method pandas doc mention https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I did the same test. Is this still due to the copy in memory issue?

Comment: But could you elaborate on why a capital letter, as opposed to a lowercase letter, make a difference when chaining with .loc

Comment: @MattR I'm not familiar enough with pandas internals to answer!

Comment: Wouldn't that be simple if we use `if a != 'W':` ?

Comment: @MattR multi index still have lot of bug ...:-), I spend whole night yesterday on git ...

Comment: @Wen, gotcha! Interestingly enough if `categories = ['A','B']` (ie, both capitals) works fine on my end. even `categories = ['A','b']` works

Comment: Since, I made that comment I fill like I have to respond.  And, I don't know.  However, it is not recommended.  [See these docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: If you guys would like to look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047140/pandas-slice-one-multiindex-dataframe-with-multiindex-of-another-when-some-leve/47047512#47047512